# Problem setting up DL360G5 with scsi RAID

Tags: hardware-raid, hard-drive

I have a problem with reinstalling OS on a DL360G5.

The BIOS [F9] do not detect any disc controllers and the HP SmartSetup did not find any compatible controllers.

Inside the server, the two SCSI disks are conncted to a RAID controller using BCM8603 chipset.

How is disc contoller supposed to be setup? I have tried to do a full BIOS reset.

**EDIT**

At the moment we suspect that the Smart Array controller E200i/412205-001 is broken.

Are there any status LED's that indicate failure or success during start up? At the moment all LED's are off.

2010-03-22, We have not made any progress so far. The SmartArray controller is suspect to be broken.

Comment: If there is a raid controller present, but for some reason it does not work. Shouldnt there be a notification regarding hardware error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in the BIOS of the motherboard. Use the BIOS of the RAID controller.

Boot the server and wait until the disk controller BIOS messages shows and press the combination that you find  in the message.

If you do not see your RAID controller than it might be not work. Unplug the server, then open the server and try to reseat the card into the slot.

Comment: We have checked the Raid controller and it is properly mounted. According to manuals the raid controller should be accessible using [F8], but that triggered the ILO config menu. I disabled ILO in the hope that the RAID controller would show up, but that did not help.

Comment: Re-enbling the iLO is pain (if needed in the future), so maybe disabling the iLO wasn't really necessary. Pay attention to what the prompt says before you press any F button.  When the prompt appears on the screen during boot to start ORCA, press F8.

Comment: It should say "SmartArray" while it's initializing. I'll appear just like any of the other messages, such as iLO. If you're not seeing that message, it's not working (reseating it might fix the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to re-install the same OS as before?
If it's a Windows Server OS you are trying to install, while the setup is loading you can press F6 to load the appropriate RAID controller drivers:
[image]
<sub>(source: [gur.in](http://gur.in/images/winserv/window2.jpg))</sub>

Where you download the drivers is up to you, Google is your friend.  By the way you will need to place the drivers on a Floppy disc.

Comment: At the moment we suspect that the RAID controller is broken

Comment: Win 2000+ has the drivers for basic SmartArray functionality. I doubt that's the problem here.